# How to install Yeoman?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, yeoman

I am trying to install Yeoman and I am following instructions on Yeoman official site but I have two problems. One is when I am trying to install Yeoman on Windows, problem after  this step:

```
npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli
```

This is my terminal:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! yo@1.8.4 postinstall: `yodoctor`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the yo@1.8.4 postinstall script 'yodoctor'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the yo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     yodoctor
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs yo
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls yo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/dev7/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

> Follow the steps below to get up and running with yeoman in windows
>   system. First Install Ruby dependencies

**Install Ruby for Windows from http://rubyinstaller.org/**

Open Command prompt.
Check ruby version to confirm if ruby path is set. `ruby -v.` If this command fails, check if path of your ruby installation is added to environment variables or not. If path is not set (for ruby), add the path manually.
        Installed bundler : gem install bundler
        Install Compass : gem install compass

**Install git tools**

```
    Install Github for windows from http://windows.github.com/
    Install git from http://msysgit.github.io/. Before installing read the instruction for installing git in windows for use with bower. (optional step, only perform in bower not working)
```

**Install node dependencies**

```
    Install node.js from http://nodejs.org/. Make sure you check the option Add path to environment variables while installing.
```

Open command prompt.

```
Install bower : npm install -g bower
Install grunt-cli : npm install -g grunt-cli
Install yeoman : npm install -g yo
```

**Extra step for angular fanboys:**

```
    Install yeoman angular generator : npm install -g generator-angular
```

You can do all the above steps (expect installing node) in one command as well.

```
npm install -g bower grunt-cli yo generator-angular
```

Now you have everything you need to run yeoman and you also have installed angular project generator.

[Source](https://sumankpaul.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/how-to-setup-yeoman-in-windows-from-scratch/)

Comment: Thank you but I have problem with this command Install grunt-cli : npm install -g grunt -cli     After that I have error in command promt says : Please include the following file with any support